# Generate anonymous number for string property with AutoFixture

Tags: c#, unit-testing, autofixture

I'm unit testing some mapping methods, and I have a source property of type string which is mapped to a destination property of type integer.

So I would like AutoFixture to create the source object with an anonymous integer for the specific string property, not for all string properties.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The best way to solve this would be to [create a *convention based* custom value generator](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/10/19/ConventionbasedCustomizationsWithAutoFixture.aspx) that assigns the string representation of an anonymous numeric value to the specific property, **based on its name**.

So, to give an example, assuming you have a class like this:

```
public class Foo
{
    public string StringThatReallyIsANumber { get; set; }
}
```

The custom value generator would look like this:

```
public class StringThatReallyIsANumberGenerator : ISpecimenBuilder
{
    public object Create(object request, ISpecimenContext context)
    {
        var targetProperty = request as PropertyInfo;

        if (targetProperty == null)
        {
            return new NoSpecimen(request);
        }

        if (targetProperty.Name != "StringThatReallyIsANumber")
        {
            return new NoSpecimen(request);
        }

        var value = context.CreateAnonymous<int>();

        return value.ToString();
    }
}
```

The key point here is that the custom generator will only target properties named `StringThatReallyIsANumber`, which in this case is our *convention*.

In order to use it in your tests, you will simply have to add it to your `Fixture` instance through the `Fixture.Customizations` collection:

```
var fixture = new Fixture();
fixture.Customizations.Add(new StringThatReallyIsANumberGenerator());

var anonymousFoo = fixture.CreateAnonymous<Foo>();
```

Comment: Thanx, I updated the class a little, so the constructor takes the name of the property as a parameter. Thereby I can use the class in other places as well.

Comment: This was also helpful in a case I had where I needed to generate valid URLs for specific string properties instead of the GUID-based defaults.